# Add selected options to Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 in "Ajax mode" so I get the options from an API endpoint. But I need to prefill it with some selected options via Javascript after the user starts to type.

I've try to append it to the `<select></select>` and also to the rendered list, but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case that someone is struggling with the same

```
var option = new Option("text", "id");
option.selected = true;

$("#id").append(option);
$("#id").trigger("change");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JorgeAnzola/skztts0c/1/)

Comment: Thanks, save me lots of time ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var option = new Option("text", "id", false, true);
```

The fourth parameter sets the options actual selected

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it (if you don't want to add a new option and use the existing ones):

```
  $("#the-select")
    .val($("#the-select")
      .val()
      .concat([array_of_existing_values]));
  $("#the-select")
    .trigger("change");
```

HTH